# How to load namespace System classes?

Tags: c#, oop, class, namespaces, system

I have little question. I found this on internet:

```
Type t = typeof(MyClass);
MethodInfo[] mi = t.GetMethods();
```

Is there any way how to do same thing with namespaces? Or is there any another way to get all classes with names and System.Type instances? Long time ago I found something about listing the library. Please anybody help me.

Comment: You can get all classes from the system assembly using this little hack: `typeof(string).Assembly.GetTypes()`.

Comment: Ok. But what should I do if I need to get it from for example System.IO ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all Namespaces in an assembly using Reflection (DotNET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549198/finding-all-namespaces-in-an-assembly-using-reflection-dotnet)

Comment: And pls write it as answer. I'll mark it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that would get everything in the mscorlib assembly, not System.

Comment: Each type has a `Namespace` property, you can filter on it using LINQ or a `foreach` loop, whatever you prefer.

Comment: Oh, the `System.IO` stuff will be there too: `mscorlib` has 2500+ classes.

Comment: Remember that there is no one-to-one (or one-to-many) relation between assemblies and namespaces. An assembly may contain many namespaces (not a big surprise) but a namespace may also be defined in multiple assemblies. Essentially the relationship is many-to-many. Asking for all the types in a particular namespace is not well defined unless you mention which assemblies to search.

Comment: Yes, I now it. But I made a mistake 'cause sometimes when I'm using sockets I must add System.Net into references in Viusal Studio...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all classes from the `mscorlib` assembly using this little hack: `typeof(string).Assembly.GetTypes()`. You can further filter on it by `FullName` or `Namespace` property.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all of the classes in a particular namespace, you could do something like this:

```
var types = from type
            in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            where type.Namespace == "System"
            select type;
```

This will look in all loaded assemblies for any type in the namespace `System`. You could of course change "System" to anything else you'd like, such as "System.IO".

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your solution seems great, but he was first.